# Inline Syntax Highlighting in MediaWiki

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki

Is there any MediaWiki extension that supports **inline** syntax highlighting? (i.e. with support for code snippets embedded within regular text paragraphs)

I currently use [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi), but I'm not sure it supports inline highlighting.

Comment: For info: for *not inline*, the simplest solution is to put a space character at the start of the line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add `enclose="none"` to your `<source>` tag:

```
There is <source lang="mylanguage" enclose="none">inline code</source> in this paragraph.
```

Comment: That indeed works! However, 1) the `code` piece of text looks (too) small(er) and 2) isn't there a way to say something like `<b-incode>code</b-incode>` and actually mean `<source lang="bash" enclose="none">code</source>`?

Comment: Update: The supported tag is now `<syntaxhighlight lang="mylanguage" inline>inline code</syntaxhighlight>` although the above still works for compatibility. Also, since [June 2015](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/218584/) MediaWiki uses [Pygments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygments) instead of GeSHi. For more info, see: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution is using: `<code>put your code here</code>`

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with my browser's settings (read, the fonts I use) but I can't tell much of a difference, i.e. distinguish code from normal text.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: please try another browser and Ctrl-F5 to force a refresh.

Comment: @Nikos: Use custom CSS styles to enhance the look of your `code` parts (http://yourwiki/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css).

Answer (score 2):

While using `<code>inline code</code>` or, for example, `<syntaxhighlight lang="groovy" inline>inline code</syntaxhighlight>` works typing this in is a real pain, especially if you deal with a lot of code snippets.

If the wiki is under your control you can [extend its markup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extending_wiki_markup). The example below shows how to shorten the above to `<c>inline code</c>` and `<sg>inline code</sg>` respectively using [tag extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions) method.

Create `Customtags` directory for your new extension in your MediaWiki extensions directory (`MW_HOME/extensions/`). In this directory create a `customtags.php` file with the following content:

```php
<?php

$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'customtagsInit';

function customtagsInit(Parser $parser) { 

    // parameters: custom tag, custom renderer function
    $parser->setHook('c', 'customRenderShortCode');
    $parser->setHook('sg', 'customRenderSourceGroovy');

    return true;
}

function customRenderSourceGroovy($input, array $args, Parser $parser, PPFrame $frame) {
    $input = '<syntaxhighlight lang="groovy" inline>' . $input . '</syntaxhighlight>';
    $wikiparsed = $parser->recursiveTagParse($input, $frame);
    return $wikiparsed;
}

function customRenderShortCode($input, array $args, Parser $parser, PPFrame $frame) {
    $wikiparsed = $parser->recursiveTagParse($input, $frame);
    return '<code>' . $wikiparsed . '</code>';
}

?>
```

Finally register this extension in `LocalSettings.php` and you are good to go:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Customtags/customtags.php";
```

In a similar way you can create short tags for larger blocks of code.

Comment: You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

First, tag the characters you care about with `span, code, source, div, p,` etc.   For inline with minimal changes, span is probably what you are looking for.

Second, apply a style to the tagged characters.  For highlighting you probably want something like `background: yellow`

Example:

`Highlights  like <span style="border:thin solid green; background: yellow;">this</span> really draw the eye.`

Answer (score 0):

I found that enclosing the entire block with `<pre></pre>` showed the format the best.